# Converting cells to a range of cells within a BeforeClose VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked and tried all the arrays and set functions but when I run it in the program it does not work.
This is my program

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Sheets("Check").Range("G16").Value = "Special Request" And _
Range("G17").Value = "" Or _
Range("G18").Value = "" Or _
Range("G19").Value = "" Or _
Range("G20").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please verify that all tabs are check using the check tab"
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Instead of naming each cell i would like to insert ranges. an example will be; 
G17:G20 or 
G24:G29 or
G33:G38 then_

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your first range is relative to sheet "Check", but the others are relative to the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` to count the number of non blank values in the range and compare it against the ranges cell count.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Range("G17:G20,G33:G38")
    If Sheets("Check").Range("G16").Value = "Special Request" And _
        WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) < Target.count Then

        MsgBox "Please verify that all tabs are check using the check tab"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```